# Stereo Audio Device Doesn't Show up but Hands-free Audio Device Does

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, wireless-headset

I have an Argon Soul headset which connects to my ASUS laptop via Bluetooth. Usually there are two playback devices, the Stereo device and the Hands-free device "Argon Sould Hands-Free AG Audio". Usually, the stereo device would be the default playback device.

Recently the Stereo device has completely disappeared when I connect my headphones, and now I only have the low-quality monophonic Hands free device. This happened after I rebooted my computer recently.

How would I retrieve the stereo output? This problem has not occurred with my other devices like my phone.

Comment: Recent Windows update? MS has unceremoniously dumped some older protocols, leaving many people in this situation.

Comment: I remember now, it did happen after a recent Windows update.

Comment: I think this is what I was thinking of - it's somewhere to start, at least - https://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2019/08/24/microsoft-windows-10-update-problem-bluetooth-warning-upgrade-windows-10/#1c895b4467f2